# Python 3.3 install "configobj"

Tags: python, pip, configobj

could somebody walk me through installing the python `configobj` module? I downloaded it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/4.7.2)
 but it throws an error during installation

```
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have `Python 3.3.2` installed and the problem is known about the different syntax between `Python 2.7` and `3.x`. The question is, does anybody know a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x the syntax for exceptions was

```
except Exception, e
```

This was changed in py2.7 and above to the cleaner

```
except Exception as e
```

To install the correct version try using pip

```
pip install configobj
```

Edit, on second look configobj doesn't seem to support python 3.x
You now have three choices;

- Port it yourself
- Use an earlier Python version
- Find an alternative module or roll your own.

Edit Edit,

Turns out someone has already done started on the hard work but its unreleased.

https://bitbucket.org/zubin71/configobj-py3/wiki/Home

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I used this in one of my previous projects. However I used it from this repo
https://bitbucket.org/pkumar/configobj-py3/src